# Argument Types do not match QueryExtender

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an Entity I'm pulling three columns from Title (nvarchar(256)), Popularity (int), and Type (int). I'm then trying to use QueryExtender on a radiobuttonlist to allow the end user to filter out all but specific results but I keep getting an "Argument Types do not match" error. Here is the actual code:

```
 <asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="EntityDataSource1">
    <asp:SearchExpression DataFields="Type" SearchType="StartsWith">
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="rblTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </asp:SearchExpression>
 </asp:QueryExtender>

 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTypes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
     RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Active Inside</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">Semi-Active Inside</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3">Inactive Inside</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="4">Chair Game</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="5">Active Outside</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="6">Semi-Active Outside</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="7">Inactive Outside</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="8">Water Game</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="9">Messy Game</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="10">Trick</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess: `SelectedValue` is a `string`. It doesn't match with `Type` which is an `int`. You could try to specify the `DbType` explicitely in the `ControlParameter`:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="rblTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
    DbType="Int32" />
```

**Edit**

`asp:SearchExpression` seems only to be for text based search which means that the data fields you specify must be of type `string` which is not the case for your `Type` column. Instead of a SearchExpression you could try an `asp:RangeExpression` and specify the same value for minimum and maximum, namely the `SelectedValue` of the RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender1" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="EntityDataSource1">
  <asp:RangeExpression DataField="Type" MinType="Inclusive" MaxType="Inclusive">
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="rblTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="rblTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
  </asp:SearchExpression>
</asp:QueryExtender>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd guess the same. Unfortunately, I tried what you suggested and that didn't work either. :(